# How to provision a SitePolicy in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom

How do i provision a site policy in SharePoint Online? OnPrem this is done quite easy withtin the xmldocuments but i cant find an easy way to do this online. Can anyone point me in the right direction.

To be clear i dont wanna add CTH.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[PnP Powsershell](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/sharepoint/sharepoint-pnp/sharepoint-pnp-cmdlets?view=sharepoint-ps)** to get the provision template which include only the site Policy. this template file is a XML document.

Connect to source web-site

```
Connect-PnPOnline -Url "https:\\contoso.sharepoint.com\site\my_site"
```

Get Site Policy

```
Get-PnPProvisioningTemplate -Handlers SitePolicy -Out D:\sitePolicy.xml
```

Import the template to target web site after making connection, run this command

```
Apply-PnPProvisioningTemplate -Path D:\sitePolicy.xml
```

Comment: Never thought about that approach, Gonna try tonight, thanks for tip.

Comment: This only adds a sitepolicy that is already existing. There is no information in the xml that can create the dates or rules that are needed for creating a policy. I wanna be able to set the date for readonly and removing in the xml since they will differ from site to site.

Comment: This provides you the existing site policy template that can be moved to other sites. But you can still manually Add/edit the policy parameters, attributes etc. Just make sure u don't break the XML structure.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0"?>
<pnp:Provisioning xmlns:pnp="http://schemas.dev.office.com/PnP/2016/05/ProvisioningSchema">
<pnp:Preferences Generator="OfficeDevPnP.Core, Version=2.17.1708.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=3751622786b357c2"/>
<pnp:Templates ID="CONTAINER-TEMPLATE-38540025935344AAB13754946B37A406">
<pnp:ProvisioningTemplate ID="TEMPLATE-38540025935344AAB13754946B37A406" BaseSiteTemplate="STS#0" Version="1">
<pnp:SitePolicy>test</pnp:SitePolicy>
</pnp:ProvisioningTemplate>
</pnp:Templates>
</pnp:Provisioning>

Comment: this is what i get from template.  No variables to change there